# XSL Transformation in ASP.NET 2 HTTP Handler

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, httphandler, dtd

In a ASP.NET Web[Forms] Application (.NET 4.5.2) I have the following HTTP Handler (`ProcessRequest` method) which works correctly:

```
XmlReader document = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse });
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(xsltPath);
transform.Transform(document, null, writer);

context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
context.Response.Write(writer.ToString());
```

I need to use the above code in a HTTP Handler in a ASP.NET WebSite project (.NET 2.0). I know the code needs to be modified as follows (because of differences between the .NET versions):

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;

XmlReader document = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, xmlSettings);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(xsltPath);
transform.Transform(document, null, writer);

context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
context.Response.Write(writer.ToString());
```

**I expected the code would work in both cases but No**. In the second case, testing with exactly the same XML and XSLT files I always get the following error:

`Expected DTD markup was not found. Line 1, position 1.`

in line:

`transform.Transform(document, null, writer);`

which I cannot really explain why. As said, the XML and XSLT files are exactly the same in both cases and the HTTP Handlers are correctly registered in `web.config`.

**UPDATE:** Here is how the XML input begins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/2.3/" [
  <!ENTITY bull "&#8226;">
  <!ENTITY copy "&#169;">
]>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the input look like?  It looks as if setting the ProhibitDTD flag to false is not just not prohibiting the DTD but requiring it.  What does the documentation say?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen I do need to process the DTD. I updated the question to include an extract from the XML input.

Comment: When you dereference the URI `http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/2.3/` do you get a DTD?  I don't; I get an HTML document.  Do you think that could explain why you are getting the message "Expected DTD not found"?  What happens if you point at the NLM 2.3 DTD instead of at an HTML document telling humans where to find the NLM 2.3 DTD?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Correct. If I use the URI where the DTD really is (http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/2.3/journalpublishing.dtd) it works. Thank you (you may provide your comment as an answer and I will accept it). Well, I guess, the opposite question now stands: why does it work in .NET 4.5.2? :)